# Physics of the tablecloth trick- why top objects tip over

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

In the tablecloth trick where the cloth is pulled off, with dishes etc. on top of it, I was wondering why is it that tall objects tend to tip **forward**?

Let's say that we are pulling the cloth to the right and there is a tall cuboid on top of it. We are also pulling the cloth fast enough such that it is the maximum static friction that is acting to the right on the cuboid.

Hence we can use F=ma and $F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}$ to work out various things.

However, the only forces acting on the cuboid are its weight, the reaction force and the friction (to the right). If we take moment about the bottom left edge of the cuboid, the only force that can have a moment is its weight (assuming that at the moment of toppling the reaction force is acting at the edge), so I don't see what causes the object to tip **forward**?

Comment: I think you need some evidence for your claim that tall objects tip forward. In this video https://youtu.be/lK1ci50DUgc?t=59s the objects all tip backwards, like you would expect.

Comment: @Luke Pritchett I'm sorry, I've seen the video and that motion was what I meant- backwards, I just called it forward for some reason. I was actually wondering, could this backward motion simply be due to the torque caused by the friction which would cause this tipping (rotational) motion seen?

Comment: Ah, you should edit the question then.

Comment: More on [tablecloth trick](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+tablecloth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three forces on an object as the tablecloth moves: the object's weight, a force from the table holding it up, and the friction from the table cloth pulling the object forward.

Consider the torque around the center of mass of the object. The force of gravity passes through the center of mass so it does not contribute any torque, as does the normal force from the table (at least right at the start). However, the friction force does provide a torque, which will cause the object to rotate around its center of mass as it accelerates forward.

The direction of rotation is the one where the base of the object moves in the same direction as friction (forward), and the top of the object moves in the opposite direction (backwards). This is the backwards tipping motion.